# Xpath:How to get data from div tag

Tags: c#, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

```
<div id="caption">
<div>
    Position: Passenger Side Front
    <br></br>
    Color: Black
    <br></br>
    Finish: Smooth / Paintable
    <br></br>
    Part Brand: LatchWell
    <br></br>
    Lifetime Warranty
</div>
```

I need xpath  that should  fetch **Part Brand :** values.My desired OP is
**LatchWell**

Here is my code :

```
  tag = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='caption']//div");
            if (tag != null)
            {
                wi.Brand = tag.InnerText.Trim();
            }
```

I am not able to split by using split functions because the data above and below Part Brand are dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an HTML markup that isn't selectable with HtmlAgilityPack except for the two `<div>` tags, you'll have to use some kind of other method such as Regex evaluation.

Assuming that the `Part Brand: something <br><br>` always exists in your code, you could select the text between `Part Brand:` and `<br>` and get the brand name.

```
HtmlNode brandNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='caption']//div");
string brand = Regex.Match(brandNode.InnerHtml, "Part Brand: (.*?)<br>").Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(brand);
```

This simple use of `Regex.Match(string, regexp)` will output `Latchwell`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can select that particular HTML line using XPath, for example :

```
var tag = htmlDoc.DocumentNode
                 .SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='caption']/div/text()[contains(.,'Part Brand:')]");
//given html input as posted in this question, following will print : "LatchWell"
Console.WriteLine(tag.InnerText.Trim().Replace("Part Brand: ", ""));
```